# Centos 7 pdflatex's nonstop mode doesn't seem to work

Tags: doxygen, pdflatex

I'm trying to build a reference manual based off of `Doxygen` generated `LaTeX`.

This document has several errors, mainly due to missing doc comments.

The command I used to generate the PDF file is:

```
pdflatex refman.tex -interaction=nonstopmode
```

Even with this command, I still see the '`?`' mark prompt come on the first error.

Here are my environment details:

- Centos7 64 bit
- pdflatex 6.1.1

Comment: Why didn't you use the command `make` in the latex directory?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the solution is to use this command instead:

```
pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode refman.tex
```

It seems that pdflatex expects the .tex file specified at the end of the command